# How can i secure my endpoint to be called from Sendgrid inbound parse?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have created an azure function which will be called by sendgrid inbound parse. The function scope is anonymous which means it can be called by anyone. Is there a a secure way to make function accept requests from sendgrid only?

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no other option on the SendGrid side, you could enable [function-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#authorization-keys) which can be sent as a query parameter as part of the URL.

Another level of security could be to restrict the calling IPs to that of SendGrid (if there is such a list).